# Not able to upload a file in code igniter.

Tags: codeigniter, file-upload

I'm trying to upload an image with code igniter but it does not show any success of failure message.
Please help.

**This is a file upload form**
**view- Upload_form.php**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="">

            <?php echo $error; ?>

            <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
            <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
            <br><br>

            <input type="submit" value="upload"/>

        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

**This is a view success file**
**view - upload_success.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Upload form</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1> YOUR FILE WAS SUCCESSFULLY UPLOADED </h1>
        <ul>
  <?php foreach ($upload_data  as $item => $value); ?>          

            <li><?php echo $item; ?> : <?php echo $value; ?></li>
            <?phpendforeach ;?>

        </ul>

   <?php echo anchor('upload','upload Another file'); ?>     
    </body>
</html>
```

**This is a controller file.**
**controller - upload.php**

```
<?php

class Upload extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper (array('form','url'));
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('Upload_form',array('error'=>' '));

    }

    public function do_upload(){

       $config = array(  
              'upload_path' => './uploads/',
           'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
           'max_size' => 100,
           'max_width' => 1024, //Mainly goes with images only
          'max_heigth' => 768
        );


        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))    {

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form',$error);
    }
    else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('upload_success',$data);

    }


    }

}
```

I have created uploads folder in root directory of code igniter.

Comment: You should use form_open_multipart http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/form_helper.html#form_open_multipart It's best to use form helper

Comment: please remove <form> tag in your code and use echo form_close() instead of </form>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make some changes in your code both **controller** and **view page**.And also ensure that your **uploads** folder placed in outside of **application** folder.below code is used in your view **Upload_form**

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <!--<form action="" method="post">-->

        <?php echo $error; ?>

        <?php echo form_open_multipart('upload/do_upload');?>
        <input type="file" name="userfile" size="20" />
        <br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="upload"/>

   <?php 
   form_close();
   ?>

</body>
```

and try following code in your controller **upload**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Upload extends CI_Controller {
       function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));

        }
        public function index(){
        $this->load->view('upload_form',array('error'=>' '));

    }

    public function do_upload(){

       $config = array(  
              'upload_path' => './uploads/',
           'allowed_types' => 'gif|jpg|png',
           'max_size' => 100,
           'max_width' => 1024, //Mainly goes with images only
          'max_heigth' => 768
        );


        $this->load->library('upload',$config);

    if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))    {

        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
        $this->load->view('upload_form',$error);
    }
    else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $this->load->view('upload_success',$data);

    }


    }

}
```

Comment: Is it important to define route in route.php like $route['upload_path'] = 'Upload'; . Whats the use of this.

Answer (score 0):

your upload_path might be incorrect, so here's the code I'm using:

1.add this at the top of your controller to declare the upload_path:

```
function __construct()
{   
  parent::__construct();
  $this->uploadPath = realpath(APPPATH . '../uploads');
}
```

2.change $config upload_path from

> './uploads/'

to

> $this->uploadPath

---

for more details, please see my uploadProfile Controller:

```
function upload_profilePic($userID)
    {
        //create a unique ID
        $filename = $userID. '-' .uniqid();

        //config upload
            $config=array(
                'allowed_types' =>  'jpg|jpeg|png|PNG',
                'upload_path'   =>  $this->imagePath,
                'max_size'  =>  90000,
                'file_name' =>  $filename
            );
        //upload
            $this->load->library('upload',$config);
            $this->upload->do_upload('profilePic');

        //get file data
            $data = $this->upload->data();
            $fileExtension = $data['file_ext'];

        if($fileExtension=="")
            $filename = '';
        else
            $filename=$data['file_name'];

        //
        $data = array(
            'profilePic' => $filename,
        );

        $this->db->where('userID',$userID)
        ->update('tblusers',$data);
    }
```

Comment: step 1 should be pasted inside the controller's class.

Comment: Still not working. Its not even showing any errors. Atleast IF Block should work. I have also added $route['upload'] = 'Upload'; in routes file.